# How do I pass superclass properties in subclass constructor in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, inheritance

I'm new to Kotlin. And I'm struggling with inheritance. Consider the following case.

This code is ok

```
open class BaseClass(
   val property1: String,
   val property2: String,
)
```

And this one also

```
data class ExtendedClass(
   val propety3: String
): BaseClass()
```

But here we have a compilation problem

```
val extended = ExtendedClass(
   property1 = "", 
   property2 = "", 
   property3 = ""
)
```

What is the use of open class inheritance if it's prohibited to construct sub-classes in that way? Instead I have to do something like

```
val extended = ExtendedClass(property3 = "")
extended.property1 = "",
extended.property2 = ""
```

But that trick kills immutability.

Comment: Your ExtendedClass shouldn’t compile. It’s not passing the required parameters to the super class constructor. Since your subclass has to call an actual constructor of the super class, you would define its constructor to have the parameters you want to set and you would pass them along to the super constructor. Data classes are not practical to use as a subclass of a super class that has important properties, because those properties won’t participate in the copy, equals, and hashcode functions of the data class. To make the superclass properties configurable in the data subclass

Comment: …you would have to make them open and then override them in the subclass constructor. Very ugly.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to declare the `BaseClass` as abstract and inherith its properties in the `ExtendedClass`:

```
abstract class BaseClass {
   abstract val property1: String
   abstract val property2: String
}

class ExtendedClass(
    override val property1: String,
    override val property2: String,
    val propety3: String
) : BaseClass()
```

You can then initialize the `ExtendedClass` with the 3 immutable properties:

```
val extendedClass = ExtendedClass(
    property1 = "Property 1", 
    property2 = "Property 2", 
    property3 = "Property 3"
)
```

Comment: Well, this is the solution. But the key thing of the inheritance in OOP was lost here: a code reuse. What is the point to declare all that fields in abstract class if you have to declare them one more time in concrete class. For me this is the oddest thing in Kotlin.

Comment: The situation became even more ridiculous if one wish to share near 20-30 or more common fields between some classes through supercalss

Comment: @kirill.login inheritance is more about behaviour (methods) than data. You should favor composition for data reuse (which kotlin and data classes are good at). Also, the same code in Java would be just as awkward if you want immutability - you would have to pass initial values to the super class constructor just the same (here the override is only necessary if you want a `data class`, but with a regular class you don't need to declare overridden properties in the subclass, just ask for initial values in the constructor).